# slicing data in javascript and get the title by selecting

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't want to `delete` the data, I want to slice the data and **select the title**.

```
columns: {     
      ProductID: {
        title: 'ProductId',
        editable: 'false',
        type: 'html',
      }
}
```

1. I want to slice the title inside my columns
2. I tried `[columns][ProductID][title]` but it is showing error

Comment: What do you mean by _slicing_? And can you show us *exactly* what you've tried (the exact code)?

Comment: Do you want to remove the key entirely?

Comment: i dont wan't to delete the data just i want to slice the data and select title

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`delete columns["ProductId"]["title"]`

The delete statement basically deletes the key-value pair from the JSON Object based on the key mentioned.

Comment: Note that property name is case sensitive in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Here's my contribution.

**Selecting Keys from Objects:**

```js
let columns = {
    ProductID: {
        title: 'ProductId',
        editable: 'false',
        type: 'html',
    }
}

let title = columns.ProductID.title;

console.log(title);
```

---

**Removing Keys from Objects:**

Using [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) on the objects key will remove it.

> **To Note:** The JavaScript delete operator removes a property from an object; ***if no more references to the same property are held***.

---

```js
let columns = {
  ProductID: {
    title: 'ProductId',
    editable: 'false',
    type: 'html',
  }
}

delete columns.ProductID.title;

console.log(columns);
```

Comment: From the OP *i dont wan't to delete the data just i want to slice the data and select title*

Comment: Or just simply he want's to `select` title.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```js
let columns =  {     
      ProductID: {
        title: 'ProductId',
        editable: 'false',
        type: 'html',
      }
}

columns.ProductID.title = columns.ProductID.title.slice(2)

console.log(columns.ProductID.title);
console.log(columns)
```